# How to set up dialup on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, 16.04

OK, absolutely new at Linux, installed 16.04.  How do I get dialup going with it, since that is all I have available?

Answer (score 0):

the package you are looking for is called *[wvdial](https://wiki.debian.org/Wvdial)*... to install it open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y wvdial`, type your password (no characters will be displayed) and wait till executed.

for further information you can also have a look at this site: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wvdial

---

if you want to use a graphical interface *gnome-ppp* is a way to go... open a terminal and just type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y gnome-ppp`, type your password (no characters will be displayed) and wait till executed.

you can find more information to configure a dialup-network at the ubuntu wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto/SetUpDialer